# Azure DNS (reddog.microsoft.com) 10.0.1.4 Virtual Machine Template

Tags: azure, templates, elasticsearch, dns

I'm using a template to deploy an elastic cluster and am having issues with the nodes setting up/deploying correctly when I choose my own subnet. It seems this is due to how the Virtual machines by default seem to have a DNS record for their private IP address. But In my case this isn't happening.

Azure DNS (reddog.microsoft.com) 10.0.1.4

1. What is this DNS server?
2. Where is it hosted?
3. Is it automatically deployed to every VPN?
4. Why do some machines automatically get a record entry and others not?
5. How can I ensure that machines get an entry?

I am currently trying to use a template to deploy Elasticsearch. If I deploy elasticsearch by creating a subnet during deployment then I get host entries on each ubuntu VM in /etc/hosts and also an A-Record for each VM in this DNS server. The deployment is successful.

If however I choose for the template to deploy in my own subnet I find that the machines don't have each other in /etc/hosts and the DNS server doesn't contain an A-Record and therefore can't resolve each other via name. Deployment therefore fails.

The template I am deploying via the Azure portal UI:
Elastic Stack - (Elasticsearch, Kibana, X-Pack)

Any help appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

based on the IP and the dns search suffix, that a custom DNS server.  The would be configured as part of the virtual network properties or as part of the dns settings on the individual NIC.

Comment: Why do some machines automatically get a record entry and others not?
How can I ensure that machines get an entry?

Comment: I'm not sure, I own the DHCP part of the process but i don't know what's generating the hosts file as that's not covered by that process.